# Arrow Keys and Numpad Bug

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, numpad

I'm still new to linux and having this annoying bug.
Whenever I keep an arrow key pressed for longer than a second, my laptop stops scrolling through the line and starts to write the corresponding number on the numpad (2 for down, 4 for left, ...), until I press exactly that number myself.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?
I'm using ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad E560.

Thanks in advance for all replies.